# I have just started coding and am stuck solving this python problem

Tags: python, while-loop

> Write a program that always asks the user to enter a number. When the user enters the negative number -1, the program should stop requesting the user to enter a number. The program must then calculate the average of the numbers entered excluding the -1.

This is what I have come up with so far

```
num = int(input("How many number's are there?"))
total_sum = 0

avg = total_sum / num 

for n in range (num):
  number = float(input("Enter a number"))
while number <0:
  
  print = ("Average is", avg)
  
 
number >0
print(number)
  
total_sum += number
  
avg = total_sum / num 
print = ("Average is", avg)
```

I need it to stop at -1 one and still give an average of the numbers listed.

Comment: And what is the line `number >0` supposed to do? You also don't seem to have attempted to calculate an average in the while loop.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: You should use an `if` statement, not `while`. Use `break` to get out of the loop. This must have been explained by the teacher before the assignment was given.

Comment: `if number == -1: break`

Comment: You've asked the user in advance how many numbers there are going to be but that is not part of the requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. It isn't possible to help you like this, because we require **one, clear, specific question**, and right now it appears that you are too far away from writing sensible code to ask a question. Please try a simpler problem first; or try to write less of the code at a time and try to make each part work first; or try to write out - by hand, with a real pen or pencil on real paper - the exact steps that you think need to be taken in order to solve the problem (draw diagrams, if it helps).

Comment: Use `while True:` to keep looping until you break out of the loop, you don't need `for`.

Comment: Also try to check some basic ideas about the logic. For example: is it possible to find out the average, before you have found out all the numbers that will be used? Therefore, which should happen first: asking for the numbers, or trying to do the math?

Comment: Please explain what your program is actually doing, and how is that different from what it's supposed to do. Don't expect us to try just to see what happens.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned I have been prompted to use a while loop for the task and the number >0, I have just realised I forgot to edit that out as initially I assumed it was asking me to stop anything less than -1 but it isn't

Comment: @Seg There's an `Edit` button below your question (left side inline with your name, or you can click here: [edit]). Use it to add all the relevant information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy.

```
emp = []

while True:
    ques = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if ques != -1:
        emp.append(ques)
        continue # continue makes the code go back to beginning of the while loop
    else:
        if len(emp) != 0:
            avg = sum(emp) / len(emp) # average is the sum of all elements in the list divided by the number of elements in said list
            print(f"Average of all numbers entered is {avg}")
            break
        else:
            print("Give me at least one number that's not -1")
            continue # emp is empty we need at least one number to calculate the average so we go back to the beginning of the loop
```